# Create an Access report background in vector format (from Word doc)

Tags: ms-access, graphics

I want to make a .EMF file (or other format, see below) to use as the background of an Access report (Invoice).
The source file is a .DOC with special formatting (vertical line, all the company info  in the left margin).
How can I convert a Word doc to EMF ? Or another (vector) format if it gives graphically perfect results and is usable as report background in Access...
Thanks

Comment: Is the EMF creation something you want scripted, or is this just something you need at design time in your reports?

Comment: Not scripted, just one shot, for design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering myself for whom it may interest: I finally had it done by:

- printing the word doc to a PDF
- opening the PDF in Adobe Illustrator and Exporting it to EMF.

I made the comparison of the *printed* output using an EMF background and a PNG background, and the difference is HUGE. The extra quality of the EMF background is really worth the extra work.
This was not a programming question per se, but still a developer question.

---

Edit: I found that [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) sometimes makes a better job than Illustrator for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a nice EMF from a composition of vector graphics done in Word, Word may refuse to keep the vector data and just render the whole group as a pixel based image when you export the resulting selection/composition/group as EMF.

But if you have also access to a copy of PowerPoint on the same machine, just select all together and copy the composition, move over to PowerPoint and paste it and export/save the composition as EMF from there. Even if the objects are first grouped in PowerPoint and the group is copied back, the result has better export results e.g. in EMF and PDF.

We also had excellent results with EMF converted from vector EPS or PDF by using commandline calls to Inkscape (especially for batch convert of lots of files). The resulting files give excellent quality as background in other MS Office documents.

Pitfall RGB. EMF works in eg. Indesign as well, so you can use the files for multiple use cases without providing too much files. But be aware that the MS Office Suite Family was usually only using RGB files. Unintended use of RGB Black after conversion may create excessive toner/ink usage on colour printers. I cannot claim this for the latest versions beyond Office 2013. So test it!

Answer (score -1):

Can't you select the art and "paste special" in Access & select ".emf" from the options. If you have Adobe Illustrator u can copy & paste into there & should be be able to export the file as a .emf

Comment: No, there is not paste for that. It's a parameter of the Report/form since it extends across all sections, on the whole page. If you paste, it will be within a section.

Comment: If it's just a line you're trying to draw, have you looked at the Line command? I use it all the time to draw vertical lines on reports that can span sections.

Comment: @David: I know the Line command. There's a bit more then that. A sample pdf is here: http://goo.gl/ij6Hh  I think I probably did that with Illustrator at the time. I am surprised that it is so difficult to find a working EMF printer or converter, while that format seems to be the pivot of Windows printing. And I remember that I tried several file formats and that one was really the best in terms of rendering and size. It is about the only *vector* format allowed for that purpose (reports)

Comment: If your real issue is just saving as EMF format, then I'd say your question doesn't belong on SO. I just checked in two graphics programs installed on this computer (Irfanview and PaintShop Pro) and both allow SAVE AS in EMF format. Seems like a pretty common capability, as my installation of Irfanview is recent, but PSP is 10 years old.

Comment: Thanks David, I will see that. If one of them can open a PDF, that could be my solution. And, you're right, this is NOT a question that really pertains to SO. But I have nowhere to go. Booooo :-/

Comment: Well, neither can open a PDF, but one can export a PDF to graphics and use that (I use the free PDF995 editing tools, since I need the editing functionality too seldom to pay for it).